# SQL. Максимальные значения во вложенном запросе

Tags: mysql

Написал я запрос

```
SELECT A.client, MAX(A.summ) FROM
(
    SELECT Client.Client AS client, SUM(Sum) AS summ FROM Sales
    INNER JOIN Client ON (Sales.ClientKey = Client.ClientKey)
    GROUP BY client
) AS A
```

В нем выводится одно максимальное значение суммы покупки клиента. Хочу вывести из вложенного запроса все максимальные значение, а не один (к примеру SUM(Sum) - сумма покупки могут быть у нескольких клиентов одинаковые). Я пробовал так:

```
SELECT A.client, A.summ FROM
(
    SELECT Client.Client AS client, SUM(Sum) AS summ FROM Sales
    INNER JOIN Client ON (Sales.ClientKey = Client.ClientKey)
    GROUP BY client
) AS A WHERE A.summ = (SELECT MAX(A.summ) FROM A)
```

Но у меня ошибка.
Если есть удачные примеры запроса, чем мой, покажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH
cte1 AS ( SELECT Client.Client, 
                 SUM(Sales.`Sum`) AS Summ
          FROM Sales
          JOIN Client USING (ClientKey)
          GROUP BY Client.Client ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT Client, Summ, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Summ DESC) rnk
          FROM cte1 )
SELECT Client, Summ
FROM cte2
WHERE rnk=1;
```

То же, но в формате подзапросов

```
SELECT Client, Summ
FROM ( SELECT Client, Summ, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Summ DESC) rnk
       FROM ( SELECT Client.Client, 
                 SUM(Sales.`Sum`) AS Summ
              FROM Sales
              JOIN Client USING (ClientKey)
              GROUP BY Client.Client 
            ) cte1 
    ) cte2
WHERE rnk=1;
```

Comment: почему-то мой mysql не поддерживает WITH. Версия "Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.11-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1"

Comment: @РобертГатри *10.4.11-MariaDB* должна поддерживать - во всяком случае, [документация](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/with/) утверждает именно так: *Common Table Expression WITH was introduced in MariaDB 10.2.1.*

Comment: а другие способы без WITH есть?

Comment: Есть. Длинно только...

Comment: я так понимаю это нужно одинаковые вложенные запросы в несколько мест вставлять?

Comment: @РобертГатри Добавил.

Comment: вообще мне это нужно будет переносить на MS SQL Server 2012, а там судя по документации with нету.

Comment: @РобертГатри Я фигею... походу это Вы документацию смотрите так, что сервер отказывается выполнять то, что вроде бы может и должен... [WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/ms175972%28v%3dsql.110%29).